# how to animate a div towards different direction and fade out using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to build an animation effect where **a div will float towards another div and when it reaches to the second div area, the floating div will fade out**.Moving direction will be like this **https://www.dropbox.com/s/2bpdbtycajuuk6a/1.JPG?dl=0** .For better understanding , i am providing my html and css code here.

> html code....

```
<div id="outer_div"> 
            <div class='a'>A</div>
            <div class='b'>B</div>
            <div class='c'>C</div>
            <div class='d'>D</div>
        </div>
```

> and css ....

```
div.a {
    width: 50px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:red;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    top:450px;
    left: 225px;
}

div.b {
    width: 50px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:green;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    top:225px;
    left: 0px;
}

div.c {
    width: 50px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:yellow;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:450px;
    top:0px;
    left: 225px;
}



div.d {
    width: 50px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:pink;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:225px;
    top:225px;
    left: 450px;
}

#outer_div {
    width: 500px;
    height:500px;
    background-color:blue;
    position:fixed;
}
```

Here are 4 divs(**A, B, C, D**). **A** div will float where others are still. At first **A** div will float towards **D** and when touches **D** , **A** will fade out. Second, **A** div will float from the beginning towards **C** and when touches **C** , **A** will fade out. Third, **A** div will float from the beginning towards **B** and when touches **B** , **A** will fade out. Again the annimation will begin from the beginning and continue as before and **this procedure will continue for 52 times**.I have tried with this script but failed to do it .

> Scripts ....

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
            animateDiv();

        });

        function makeNewPosition() {

            // Get viewport dimensions (remove the dimension of the div)
            var h = -$("#outer_div").height() - 50;
            var w = -$("#outer_div").width()/2 - 50;

            var nh = h;
            var nw = w;
//            var nh = Math.floor(Math.random() * h);
//            var nw = Math.floor(Math.random() * w);

            return [nh, nw];

        }

        function animateDiv() {
            var newq = makeNewPosition();
            var oldq = $('.a').offset();
            var speed = calcSpeed([oldq.top, oldq.left], newq);

            $('.a').animate({top: newq[0], right: newq[1]}, speed, function () {
                animateDiv();
            });

        }
        ;

        function calcSpeed(prev, next) {

            var x = Math.abs(prev[1] - next[1]);
            var y = Math.abs(prev[0] - next[0]);

            var greatest = x > y ? x : y;

            var speedModifier = 0.1;

            var speed = Math.ceil(greatest / speedModifier);

            return speed;

        }
```

I couldn't understand the **direction concept** of the floating div **A** and how i am gonna detect that my floating div is at in the region of other div. Please help me with its solution and how can i understand animation direction concept in jquery(some reference can help a lot) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var a = $(".a")
    , elems = $("#outer_div div").not(a)
    , pos = function () {
        return $.map(elems, function (el, i) {
            return $(el).css(["left", "top"])
        }).reverse()
    }
    , curr = 0
    , max = 52
    , speed = 1000;
    (function animateDiv(el, p, curr, max) {
        if (!!p.length) {
            $(el)
            .animate({
                    left:p[0].left
                  , top: (parseInt(p[0].top) + $(el).height())
            }, speed, function () {
                $(this).fadeOut(100, function () {
                    $(this)
                    .css({"top": "450px", "left":"225px"})
                    .fadeIn(0);
                    p.splice(0, 1);
                    animateDiv(this, p, curr, max)
                })

            })
        } else if (curr < max) {
            ++curr;
            console.log(curr, max);
            animateDiv(el, pos(), curr, max)
        }
    }(a, pos(), curr, max))
});
```

```css
div.a {
    width: 50px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:red;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    top:450px;
    left: 225px;
}
div.b {
    width: 50px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:green;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    top:225px;
    left: 0px;
}
div.c {
    width: 50px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:yellow;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:450px;
    top:0px;
    left: 225px;
}
div.d {
    width: 50px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:pink;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:225px;
    top:225px;
    left: 450px; 
}
#outer_div {
    width: 500px;
    height:500px;
    background-color:blue;
    position:fixed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div id="outer_div">
    <div class='a'>A</div>
    <div class='b'>B</div>
    <div class='c'>C</div>
    <div class='d'>D</div>
</div>
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/83h17z25/2/

Comment: this code is good. But i have forgotten to mention that A div should animate like this. https://www.dropbox.com/s/2bpdbtycajuuk6a/1.JPG?dl=0 . Sorry for the inconvenience. Moving at this kind of direction was my actual problem  :P @guest271314

Comment: Thats great :D @guest271314